# Creating controlled fluids?

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

I want to have a fluid simulation with a controllable output direction, similar to a water gun. How can I accomphish this?

Reference image:
https://www.gannett-cdn.com/-mm-/b510152d57df004945f4582cd19828a87c81681e/c=6-0-2555-1440/local/-/media/2015/05/29/RenoGroup/RGJ/635684613849077376-Splatoon-Weapons.jpg
https://pa1.narvii.com/6630/7ed008baca03faa8f41bede9d638d4c62f1a0e98_hq.gif
Note how there is an "explosion'" of liquid at the base of the gun, and a "shot" coming from the center.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a crude example to improve upon -- a "water gun" blend file.   I use several components:

1. I select the Cylinder for the Geometry (initial burst of water) and
   use Object -> Quick Effects -> Fluid, and edit the initial velocity to be some large number in the correct direction.
2. I duplicate that Cylinder and change the Flow Behaviour to Inflow, also with a large initial velocity
3. I duplicate a cylinder, change it to be and Effector -> Collision type as the "gun barrel.  Not I need at least a 0.5 surface thickness for it to be effective (bug in blender IMHO), and therefore also scale it to be a bit larger to contain and direct the liquid flow.  I also Edit the Collision cylinder to remove one end face where the liquid will come out.

I then make the Collision the Parent object of the fluid Geometry and Inflow objects, so I can then animate the Barrel (move, rotate) as needed.  I also need to make the Liquid Domain large enough as needed for the distance the liquid will travel.  I played around a bit with Flip particle radius and Resolution Divisions to be adequate, as also with the Sampling Sub-steps on the three objects.

[image]

Enjoy.

Comment: I will try this out ltr when i have time ty